# PostgreSQL Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL under Ubuntu 16.04 and want to work with a database
`postgis_in_action`.

I logged into the database and created a schema and two tables.
I'd like to work with `pgadminIII` and so tried to connect to my database.
The error is the following:

```
<12:09:24: Fehler: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgis_in_action"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgis_in_action">.
```

What's wrong with the password authentication? Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you logging in from your Ubuntu server? One thing you may need to do is make adjustments to the hba.conf so that pgAdmin can connect to it..

Comment: Looks like you are trying to connect with the user  postgis_in_action. The erro reads "password authentication failed for user postgis_in_action " May be you could try  connecting as postgres first. Did you create the tables after logging in as postgis_in_action?

Comment: Yes, I created the tables after logging into postgis_in_action.

Comment: Which adjustments do I have to do in hba.conf so that I can log in with pgadmin3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have given wrong values for server properties and hence pgadmin is trying to connect using user 'postgis_in_action'.
Try connecting with postgres user.

Also make sure that the hba file (pg_hba.conf) has connections allowed for this host (pgadmin host).

> host        postgis_in_action           postgres            127.0.0.1(ipaddress)                md5

Reload the server to apply the changes nade in pg_hba.conf.